How to check same file using NSItemProvider in iOS?
When I get some images of Photos in iPhone device using NSItemProvider by PHPickerViewController, I want to know how to check same file(image) with picked photos.
Because I use NSItemProvider, the image is copied item. It isn't original file. So, Can't compare two images directly.

I don't see why you "can't compare two images": just look to see if their derived pngData is the same.
If that's insufficient, and you really want to know whether the user has chosen the same photo from the library on two different occasions, you would need to get library read permission from the user, configure the picker appropriately, and get the PHAsset underlying each returned item; a PHAsset has a unique identifier, and so you would be able to compare unique identifiers.

I don't want to use PHAsset, because of the photo library access permission. Therefore, I used NSItemProvider to avoid to get access permission. You mean, if I want to know whether the user has chosen the same photo from the library on two different occasions, need to get the access permission of photo library? hmm.....
